# Why do we need to use standard library for string but not for int datatype?

Tags: c++

In C++, why do we need to use `#include <string>` standard library to use `std::string` datatype but we don't need anything like that for `int` or `float` datatype?

Comment: int and float are part of your CPU API (called instruction set). Strings are not.

Comment: @sturcotte06 that is nothing to do with it really , as evinced by the fact that there are plenty of other languages that have strings and ints on equal footing.

Comment: @M.M It probably is the historical basis though. The languages you are referring to are either interpreted or in some way managed; C++ maps ints and floats "directly" to the metal (sort of), whereas it simply can't do that for a string.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings well, I've used `float` on a chip with no floating point hardware, and `long` on an 8-bit CPU

Comment: @M.M I did say "sort of"! Even when a wrapper of some kind is needed to implement those things, I think it _still_ made sense to make them fundamental, because they're super-primitive. Does it make as much sense to make a dynamically-allocating auto-resizing character string fundamental? Perhaps so, particularly given how much other stuff we have in the language/library nowadays. Would it have made sense to do that in C in 1970, in a world before scripting languages and whatnot? Nah. And though `std::string` wasn't in C in 1970 at all, I still think we inherited that mindset to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a **language** and a **library**. The language takes it's origin in C where `int` and `float` are the basic types, so these types are the basics of the *language*.

The paradigm of C++ is that everything that could be implemented in the *library* should be implemented there. That means that the language covers the syntax of a `class`, `template`, etc, while the actual implementation of `std::string` is built using these basic language blocks.

To use the library you need to include the appropriate header.

Actually your question is incorrect. Fur sure `int` and `float` don't need any headers for historical reasons. But some types like `int32_t`, `intptr_t`, `uint8_t`, etc. are defined in the header .

By the way, the first STL was standartized in 1998: for many years C++ had no common standards for the utilities like containers, string management, etc. That is the reason why multiple third-party libraries exist: every vendor of the compiler had to supply a reasonable library with a bare-bones language.

Comment: Well … back when C++ was new (and even more so when C was new), on many platforms, floating-point operations were performed in software, not hardware; IBM PCs throughout the 80s, for example. Presumably, that software was in the library too. So Ritchie, at least, had to choose to make the floating-point types fundamental, not library-based. And C++ inherited that choice.

Comment: so the question boils down to why there's no string type in C which may be traced back to why B did the same. In fact in older C there's only `int` and int pointer